# Strike part of text in dropdown in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

Part of my text in `<mat-option>` needs to be striked. The problems is that the selected value loses its Html tag.

This is the drop down:

[image]

And this is the selected value:

[image]

This is the Html Code:

```
   <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start baseline">
      <span fxFlex="0 0 110px" class="text-sm text-muted-dk">Currency Position</span>
      <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
        <mat-form-field fxFlex>
          <mat-select #navigationArrowMode [formControl]="form.controls['currencyPosition']">
            <mat-option
              *ngFor="let currencyPosition of currencyPositions"
              [value]="currencyPosition"
            >
              {{ CurrencyPositionToLabelMapping[currencyPosition] }}</mat-option
            >
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The typescript code:

```
    this.PriceOrderToLabelMapping = {
      [PriceOrders.OriginalFirst]: `<del>$110</del>&nbsp;$99&nbsp;Sale`,
      [PriceOrders.SalePriceFirst]: `$99&nbsp;Sale&nbsp;<del>$110</del>`
    };
```

Comment: One option is to use strike unicode but that way I lose the font style!

Comment: What about setting it to something like `$99 (Original price: $110)` or similar instead? This omits the needed `<del>` tag.

Comment: @Edric Can't do that (due to requirements of project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to implement the `<mat-select-trigger>` element with innerHTML like:

```
 <mat-select-trigger>
       <span [innerHTML]="foodCtrl?.viewValue"></span>
    </mat-select-trigger>
```

A full example will be: **[Online Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elon3g)**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Food selection</mat-label>
  <mat-select name="foodCtrl" [(ngModel)]="foodCtrl" >
    <mat-select-trigger>
       <span [innerHTML]="foodCtrl?.viewValue"></span>
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" 
    [value]="food" >
      <span [innerHTML]="food.viewValue"></span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```